# Rotation of an unit vector in 3D space

Tags: matrices, vectors, rotations

I need to rotate an unit vector at a random point in 3D space. A point in 3D space "p" defines the base point of the unit vector. For simplicity, I want to rotate the vector around local Y axis at point "p". The orientation of local and global Y axes are same. I'm prgramming in Vb.net to compute some 3D point information. If anyone can help me some code snippets, it would be of great help. Thank you in advance.

[image: Rotate along local Y axis at point "p"]

---

To make my question clearer, here is the rotation I'm looking for

[image]

Kindly let me know the procedure to achieve the same.

Regards,
Raghav

Comment: If you’re looking for code snippets, you should try on https://stackoverflow.com/ instead.

Comment: Any suggestion??

Comment: I'm looking for the math behind the rotation. I can program it myself. Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing about the vector $v$ that attaches it to the point $p$. You can simply rotate it about the $y$-axis as if it were at the origin. P.S. Please add clarifications by editing your question, not by adding an answer.

Comment: You specifically asked for code: “If anyone can help me some [sic] code snippets, it would be of great help.”

Comment: This appeared in my review queue. I can't close this. It's such a good question.

Comment: Quaternion rotations can be a nice, compact way to do this - many languages have a quaternion library somewhere or other.

Comment: Cross-posted on the computer graphics site: https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/q/7932/106

Answer (score 1):

I think you are making it more difficult than it actually is. Translate it to the origin, rotate it, then translate it back.